# Git reset gives me "still trying to merge"

Tags: merge, git-reset

I've googled this in many different ways and can't find anyone else talking about it (at least as far as I understand).

On my office pc I was trying to find a solution to a problem I was having (so I was ahead of my remote git repo, but without committing).
That night at home I figured out the solution and pushed it to my remote repo from my home pc.

Now I'm back in work and I wanted to reset my local repo on my office pc to match the remote (and discard all my local changes).

I ran:

```
git reset --hard origin/branch1
```

I got:

```
HEAD is now at 1501f25 **Still trying to merge**
```

What does this mean?
'`Still trying to merge`' seems to indicate it didn't complete somehow, but I can't see how (and I'm having no luck finding a clear answer in the git docs).

Answer (score 0):

If a `git merge --abort` (git1.7.4+, January 2011) doesn't do it, check if you still have a [`.git/MERGE_HEAD` file](http://technosorcery.net/blog/2012/10/25/bailing-out-of-an-in-progress-git-merge/) (and delete it).

Then the `git reset` should proceed (or, since it completed, the git repo state should be coherent).
Make sure you are in the right branch you wanted to reset to `origin/branch1`.

---

As the [OP Roy Collings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2582526/roy-collings) suggests, recloning should get rid of the warning, but that means [having one's project config files versioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17260284/6309) in order to minimize the time spent to configure everything again in a new cloned repo.
Since [relative paths are supported in an Eclipse config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2819639/6309), having `.project` and `.classpath` in a git repo is possible.

Comment: Hi VonC - I gave that a go, but at the "merge abort" I got: "fatal: There is no merge to abort (MERGE_HEAD missing)."
I guess could just remove it all and clone it again, but that seems a bit harsh (and I'd have to juggle my Eclipse .project files).

Comment: @roycollings not if you include `.project` and `.classpath` in your repo ;) See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17260284/6309

Comment: I can't ... well okay, I can :), but we're a mix of devs working on the master repo (which we fork / pull request / etc..) using different IDE's and workspaces so it's something I'd rather avoid.

Comment: @roycollings but we are talking about just *your* repo, right? So either cloning that *one* repo (to get rid of the error message), and changing a few paths in your `.project`/`.classpath`, or taking this issue as an opportunity to set uniform path policies for all to use.

Comment: Mmm - I am considering this after reading the discussion your link points to there (got some very good points in it). But the fact it's just my repo becomes moot once I submit a pull request to the 'live' repo. Then it become the base that everyone else 'pull upstream's from before making their changes.

Comment: @roycollings is it possible to: 1/ clone it and check the warning is gone. 2/ replace the origin repo by the cloned one? That would mean no change whatsoever, for your settings, or for your colleagues cloning your repo.

Comment: Indeedy! I've done that and all's well now - thanks @Vonc, I'm going to consider including .project and .classpath / standardizing the paths etc... a bit more too I think. Maybe it would actually be less of a problem than I first thought.